# Is semanticseg on multiple input network matlab possible?

Tags: matlab, datastore, semantic-segmentation, multiple-input

I have a neural network that takes multiple inputs and produces a semantic segmentation output. I was able to train the network fine, but when I try to test the network performance using the function `emanticseg` matlab throws this error:

> Error using DAGNetwork/createDispatcher (line 364) Input data for a
> multiple input network must be a combined or transformed datastore.

My input is a combined datastore. I looked up the details of semanticseg and found this:

*The read function of the datastore must return a numeric array, cell array, or table. For cell arrays or tables with multiple columns, the function processes only the first column.*

Combined data stores have 2 columns, and for a multiple input network it is necessary to read both columns because they correspond to each input layer. So, is it even possible to use semanticseg on a multiple input network? How else can I get my network to segment test images so I can evaluate the performance?

Comment: Is it correct to assume that you input basically two images and want as output semantic segmentations for each image? But the evaluation function semanticseg expects a single input and output?

Answer (score 0):

I had to copy the *semanticseg* function from the matlab library and create my own version of it that can handle combinedDatastores. The *predict* function that semanticseg uses can use combined datastores, but the wrapper function cannot handle them. So I altered it. If anyone else has the same issue let me know and I can show you what I did.